How to prevent iCloud login when running a Flutter app on MacOS?
Launching the Flutter app on Mac OS (14.4.1) triggers a popup that reads:
blah@blah.com is already signed in You can keep using the already logged in iCloud account or use another one.

Question now is, why does the app trigger that popup? And how can it be avoided? The app does not use iCloud, so there's no need to sign in...

You can prevent the iCloud login popup by setting com.apple.security.ubiquity-disable to true in your app's entitlements file. This disables iCloud services for your app.

Adding it manually to the entitlements files did not work. There's also no ubiquity entitlement in xcode ->  Signing & Capabilities, so this seems to be the wrong key. Any other ideas? Thank you anyway!
